# Can registry:2 have replicas in worker nodes?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When setting up docker `registry:2` onto a docker-swarm, is it okay to have it have more than one replica and have it run in worker nodes?  It uses a CIFS volume to store the data.

I'm also running registry behind a nginx http proxy.  Which adds a bit of complexity.  However, I can at least say that I would need it on a node that I start up everything with otherwise it cannot find the image.